# If I run my array program the 0 shows up how can i remove it?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, math

```
int[][] grades = new int [3][4];
grades[0][0] = 89;
grades[0][1] = 92;
grades[0][2] = 96;
grades[0][3] = 87;
grades[1][0] = 83;
grades[1][1] = 85;
grades[1][2] = 81;
grades[2][0] = 88;
grades[2][1] = 90;
grades[2][2] = 93;
grades[2][3] = 97;
int j ;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3  ; i++ ){
    for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
        System.out.print(grades[i][j] +" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

If I run the program the result would be:

89 92 96 87

83 85 81 0

88 90 93 97

How can I remove the 0?

Comment: What do you want to remove? You have a 0 in your matrix, you can check with an if statement in the for loop for the indices you want to omit.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the indices where the matrix value is 0:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3  ; i++ ){
    for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
        if(i == 1 && j == 3) continue;
        System.out.print(grades[i][j] +" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Or skip for all zero values:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3  ; i++ ){
    for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
        if(grades[i][j] == 0) continue;
        System.out.print(grades[i][j] +" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a value for `grades[1][3]`

```
grades[1][3] = 42; /* The answer to the ultimate question; 7.5 million year optimization */
```

Or skip that index,

```
for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
    if (i == 1 && j == 3) { 
        continue; 
    }
    System.out.print(grades[i][j] +" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default value of grades[1][3] is 0 as your matrix is of type int.

Answer (score 0):

The if then statement would be the best way grades [1][3] is just defaulting to 0 because no value is set for it. You need to specify that you want to skip the zero index.

```
 class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {


   int[][] grades = new int [3][4];

grades[0][0] = 89;
grades[0][1] = 92;
grades[0][2] = 96;
grades[0][3] = 87;
grades[1][0] = 83;
grades[1][1] = 85;
grades[1][2] = 81;
grades[1][3] = 0;
grades[2][0] = 88;
grades[2][1] = 90;
grades[2][2] = 93;
grades[2][3] = 97;
int j ;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3  ; i++ ){
    for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
                if(grades[i][j] == 0) continue;

        System.out.print(grades[i][j] +" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
  }
```